# Any alternatives to editing xaml files in visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Editing xaml files in visual studio is very slow and cumbersome.
I was wondering if any of you use alternatives to editing xaml files?

Ive already tried all the ways to improve xaml eiditing like "Open document in full xaml view" etc..but it is still painfullly slow. It takes on an averagee around 15 seconds to save.

Sometimes I use regular text editor to edit files but it doesent have intellisense tho.
Anyone know of a good free alternatives that also have intellisense?
Thanks.

Comment: How big are your Xaml files?  Have you considered splitting them?  And which version of VS are you using?  VS2010 is pretty responsive in my experience, unless you have something 3rd party slowing things down...

Comment: @DanPuzey VS2010 is horrendous when opening XAML files no matter the size. I have an issue with it also.

Comment: @DanPuzey I am using VS 2010....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep!  I use the [Expression Blend from the Microsoft Expression Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/)!

[Video](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565835): Understanding and Working with XAML Code in Expression Blend 5

Comment: the link to the video says "Not Found"...it appears like a broken link

Comment: Weird.  Played for me just now. :/. It's basically an overview of blend.

Comment: Hey...expression is faster and better...but how do you get files in visual studio 2010 to open up by default in expression blend when you double click a xaml file inside of visual studio? thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  I typically keep Visual Studio and Blend open at the same time.  I edit my files in blend, then when I switch back to VS, it tells me that the file has been modified outside of the designer and asks if I'd like to update it.  I say, "Yes", and the work on the code.  Sorry, I don't know a way to launch the file in blend from Visual Studio. :(

Comment: @Darin:  What part of "free" in the original question was unclear?

Comment: @user316117 Not sure what you mean by "question" since there were multiple "questions".  I answered "I was wondering if any of you use alternatives to editing xaml files?", which although grammatically isn't a question, suggested that the user wanted to know what alternatives we use.  Also, Expression Studio has free trials.  http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/

Comment: Expression Studio is now free as of Dec 20, 2012. Maybe Darin jumped the gun a little?

Answer (score 1):

Use *notepad*, *notepad++*, or whatever text editor you like. It's just a markup!

[Kaxaml](http://kaxaml.com/) another interesting editor you may want to use.

But if you have a `VisualStudio`/`Blend`, use them, cause in latest version, if I'm not mistaken, the refactoring should be also work on it.

Answer (score 1):

[XamlPad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398%28VS.90%29.aspx). Free, lightweight and provides live preview.

Comment: XamlPad is nice for short snippets, but if I remember correctly it cannot properly handle any real world XAML files that use MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a number of them available. I haven't tried it as I use VS2010 and I don't think they would be a replacement for VS as VS has a lot of features that others don't. You can give a try to the following:

[XAML Editor (by Lary Bell)](http://lcbell4.tripod.com/SeniorProject/Senior_Project_XAML_Editor.htm)

[XAML PadX (extended)](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2006/10/31/XamlPad-Xtended-_2800_with-an-interpreter_2900_.aspx)

[XAML Hack](http://devintelligence.com/2007/11/xamlhack-a-better-xamlpad-alternative/)

[KaXaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Now there is [FAML Designer](https://www.faml.dev/) for Visual Studio.